# Xamarin IOS App Connects to IP Address but not Domain name

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, system.net

I have a simple Xamarin IOS application that connects to some Rest services using System.Net; The code snippet below shows a simple Post I used.

```
client = new HttpClient();
 var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);
var uri = new Uri(string.Format(stringUrl));
var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


try
{
    response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
}
```

The problem I have is that the app connects successfully to the rest endpoint if the URL contains the IP address of the server, however if I use the domain name on the URL instead of the IP address the IOS app will not connect and throws an exception. I know The endpoint is up and running since I can connect to the same URL endpoint  from an xamarin android version of the app but on the IOS it fails. The problem is only when using the domain name on the URL. Hopefully somebody has seen this strange behavior before. It is also worth noting that the same test on the IOS simulator works fine, but not on a real iphone. Thanks

Comment: can mobile Safari resolve the domain?

Comment: Yes I can get to the doman using Safari no problem. Its is just the app that cannot find it. I also tried changing the iphone DNS  but no luck.

Comment: which HTTP stack are you using?

Comment: I am using System.net

Comment: no, in your iOS project settings you can choose which underlying HTTP implementation is used for HTTPClient

Comment: Not sure what you mean, where can I check that in Visual Studiio 2017?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack

Comment: I am using NSUrlSession (IOS7+)

Answer (score 0):

After some research I was able to solve this problem by doing the following:

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{

```
  response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

}